# SQL Limit & Order By across joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm storing tweets, twitter users, and categorising twitter users in groups.

I have the following 4 tables

tweets:

```
tweet_id | user_id | created
-------------------------------
23452345 | 2345    | 2013-08-12
23456094 | 1234    | 2014-03-24
23097777 | 1234    | 2014-04-12
23948798 | 9999    | 2013-09-22
```

twitter_users:

```
user_id | screen_name
------------------------
2345    | michael
1234    | david
9999    | not_interested
```

twitter_social:

```
user_id | social_id
---------------------------
2345    | 34
9999    | 20
1234    | 80
```

social_categories:

```
social_id | category_id
-----------------------
34        | 3
20        | 6
80        | 3
```

I want to see the oldest tweet per user who appears in a certain social category.
The following SQL I've written doesn't seem to work. I have one row per `twitter_user` however I'm not seeing the earliest tweet

```
SELECT tu.screen_name as Handle, tw.created_at as Earliest
FROM twitter_users tu
    LEFT JOIN tweets tw
        ON tu.user_id = tw.user_id
    LEFT JOIN twitter_social ts
        ON ts.user_id = tu.user_id
    LEFT JOIN social_categories cs
        ON ts.social_id = cs.social_id
WHERE cs.category_id=3
GROUP BY Handle
ORDER BY Earliest ASC
```

**EDIT**
I wish to have results like the following

```
Handle  | Earliest
---------------------
david   | 2014-03-24
michael | 2013-08-12
```

Comment: try `MIN(tw.created_at) as Earliest`

Comment: Yeah this did it @AbhikChakraborty thank you. I thought the MIN would be too late in the query, but it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tu.screen_name as Handle
    ,MIN(tw.created_at) as Earliest
FROM twitter_users tu
LEFT JOIN tweets tw
    ON tu.user_id = tw.user_id
LEFT JOIN twitter_social ts
    ON ts.user_id = tu.user_id
LEFT JOIN social_categories cs
    ON ts.social_id = cs.social_id
WHERE cs.category_id=3
GROUP BY tu.screen_name
ORDER BY Earliest ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the earliest, it's not ASC (ascending)

```
ORDER BY Earliest ASC
```

It should be DESC (descending)

```
ORDER BY Earliest DESC
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I mean earliest as in the oldest, not the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tu.screen_name as Handle, tw.created_at as Earliest
FROM twitter_users tu
LEFT JOIN tweets tw
    ON tu.user_id = tw.user_id
LEFT JOIN twitter_social ts
    ON ts.user_id = tu.user_id
LEFT JOIN social_categories cs
    ON ts.social_id = cs.social_id
WHERE cs.category_id=3
GROUP BY Handle
ORDER BY Earliest DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tu.screen_name as Handle, min(tw.created_at) as Earliest
FROM twitter_users tu
    LEFT JOIN tweets tw
        ON tu.user_id = tw.user_id
    LEFT JOIN twitter_social ts
        ON ts.user_id = tu.user_id
    LEFT JOIN social_categories cs
        ON ts.social_id = cs.social_id
WHERE cs.category_id=3
GROUP BY tu.screen_name
ORDER BY Earliest ASC
```